# Finding mean of approximately normally distributed population

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a population of insects is approximately normally distributed, with about $20$% lighter than $46$ grams and about $25$% heavier than $91$ grams, how would you go about finding the mean of such a population?
I think the Central Limit Theorem could be used, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have: $P(X\leq 46) = 0.20$ and $P(X\geq 91)=0.25$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Which is congruent with: $P(Z\leq \frac{46-\mu}{\sigma^2})=0.20$ and $P(Z\geq\frac{91-\mu}{\sigma^2})=0.25$ for $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Use your Standard Normal Cummulative Density tables to evaluate $\frac{46-\mu}{\sigma^2}$ and $\frac{91-\mu}{\sigma^2}$ at these percentage points, then solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

$$\frac{46-\mu}{\sigma^2}=-0.8416 \quad, \quad \frac{91-\mu}{\sigma^2}=0.6745$$

$$\therefore \mu\approx 70.98\ldots\quad,\quad   \sigma^2\approx 29.68\ldots$$